# Are there federal or international law equivalents of the Maxims of Jurisprudence of the California Civil Code?

Tags: united-states, california, international, precedent, authority

Specifically, does Civ. Code § 3517 "No one can take advantage of his own wrong" have such an equivalent?

Any others are welcome or anything similar.

Comment: Worth noting  that maxims are rarely absolute. For example, most U.S. and common law jurisdictions, including California, recognize the concept of an "efficient breach" of a contract, even though it violates this maxim. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_breach

Comment: That's amazingly educational, thank you, @ohwilleke!

Comment: @ohwilleke could you suggest anything I could improve this question by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some jurisdictions codify maxims, many do not, but these maxims still exist.

*Nullus commodum capere potest de injuria sua propria* (no one can take advantage of his own wrong) is a generally recognized principle of equity, broadly connected to the principle "who comes into equity must come with clean hands" and the covenant of good faith.

Some civil law countries (e.g. France) recognizes *Nemo auditur propriam turpitudinem allegans* (no one can be heard to invoke his own turpitude).

Comment: any suggestions how I should improve this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Asset Forfeiture, which removes any property that was gained through illicit means from the person or persons who gained them.  This can range from contraband items such as drugs, illegal arms, counterfeit currency or products, or illicit goods under embargo or protective custody as well as ordinary legal items such as moneys or legal goods procured through illegal means or with proceeds of illegal actions.

"Son of Sam" style laws (the original one was unconstitutional but constitutional variants exist) work to prevent criminals from profiting off the notoriety of their actions after the fact by seizing proceeds from interviews, book deals, scripts, or other media co-operations seeking such profit or memorabilia of related to the crime or the criminal (Others may certainly profit off of this... just not the guy convicted on it.).